# Problem having 2 wifi interfaces on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, usb

I bought [this USB wifi dongle](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B01BSW2LUU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and I tried to install it on my Kubuntu 20.04 (Kubuntu 18.04 LTS upgraded recently to 20.04)

```
$lsusb
...
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac 2T2R DB WLAN Adapter
...
```

I followed [this french tutorial](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wifi_chipset_realtek_rtl8812au) that says that everything is in the repositories
So I installed `rtl8812au-dkms` package, it worked.
Then I did `sudo modprobe rtl8812au` and it also worked.

But, using `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` still gives me the same result than before: my ethernet interface, my loopback interface and my PCI wifi interface.
The GUI in Kubuntu does not add me any new interface.

So, as advised in the french tutorial, I followed instruction "in case if another method does not work", which is to compile the driver :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

Everything again went fine, but still no new interface.

Have I done something wrong? have I missed something? 
Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: Make sure that `modprobe` doesn't fail and post output of `dmesg` after running it.

Comment: `modprobe` does fail now, saying "ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8812au': Device or resource busy".  `dmesg`  confirms that: "Error: Driver 'rtl8812au' is already registered, aborting..."

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk have you got an other idea that may help me ? :-)

Comment: I asked you to provide dmesg output when loading the driver for the
first time - unload it with rmmod, load again with `insmod
./rtl8812au.ko` (*not* modprobe) and post output of `dmesg`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I think you found something. There is a crash somewhere while calling `insmod`, but `insmod` still have `$?=0`.
Here is the [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/GfHKYEtp) output

Comment: There are similar problems reported on the Internet when Linux 5.x is used. What does `uname -r` show on your system?

Comment: `uname -r` gives  `5.4.0-21-generic`

Comment: Try cloning this https://github.com/jskovjyskebankdk/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, then `git checkout kernel-5.3`, unload driver, build it, load it again.

Comment: Nice! It worked :) I now have my new wlan interface in ifconfig. It does now appear in the GUI for the network identification :-)
Thank you a lot! If you want to summarise your answers in an answer, I could accept it :)
Thank again.

Comment: ok, I'm glad it works but it might not be the end of your problems - some people reported that even though they get wlan interface they cannot connect to the access point. Can you try it?

Comment: Yes, I did connect to my network without any trouble. The remaining thing can be : should I load/unload the driver mannually or is it saved automatically and will be done at startup ?

Comment: It will not be loaded automatically, you have to load it on your own, see https://askubuntu.com/a/307375/386622. I'll convert my comments into an answer.

Comment: Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is using Linux 5.4 and there are several [similar bug
reports](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/317)
from Linux 5.x users.  The solution is to use code from `kernel-5.3`
branch from this fork
https://github.com/jskovjyskebankdk/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux:

```
$ git clone github.com/jskovjyskebankdk/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux && cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
$ git checkout kernel-5.3
```

Unload previously loaded non-functioning `rtl8812au`:

```
$ sudo rmmod rtl8812au
```

Build a new driver and load it again:

```
$ make -j$(nproc)
$ sudo insmod ./rtl8812au.ko
```